# How to send transactional email with Nodemailer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

In my Node.js application I am using **NodeMailer** to send transactional emails to the users, everything works as expected, but I want to  expand my business logic, I have form in my React.js application, where I am collecting user data like: `email, name, address`, after user submits this form my aim is to firs time send email to the admin account (`testadmin@gmail.com`) and with custom text and if it's delivered, after send confirmation text to the user gmail, what is the best way to achieve this result?

```js
const express = require('express')
const nodeMailer = require('nodemailer')
const app = express()

let mailTransport = nodeMailer.createTransport({
  service:'gmail',
  auth:{
    user:'xuser@gmail.com',
    pass:'dplcflaj21jcdtspsv22'
  }
})

const details = {
  from:'xuser@gmail.com',
  to:'yuser@gmail.com',
  subject:'New  Record',
  text:'hello my friendo',
}

app.get('/gmail', (req, res)=>{
  mailTransport.sendMail(details, (err)=>{
    if(err){
      console.log('error', err);
    }else{
      console.log('email send');
    }
  })
  res.send('connected')
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that sendMail supports promises, you can use `Promise.all` to send both messages:

```js
app.get('/gmail', async (req, res)=>{
    const userDetails = {/***/}
    const adminDetails = {/***/}

    try {
        await Promise.all([
            mailTransport.sendMail(adminDetails),
            mailTransport.sendMail(userDetails)
        ]);

        res.send('connected')
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({message: 'Something went wrong', error });
    }
})
```